# Code to calculate pythagorean theorem

Tags: c++

I'm working on an assignment with C++. Basically I take in two sides, assuming their the smaller side or the hypotenuse, then spit out the remaining side using functions. Seems easy enough, and I'm 99% sure my math is right for the function portion, but I keep getting weirdly large answers.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

double otherSideLength(double, double);

int main() {
   double a_small_side;
   double hypotenuse;
   double swapStore = 0;
   double otherSide = 0;
   cin >> a_small_side;
   cin >> hypotenuse;
   if(a_small_side == hypotenuse){
      cout << "ERROR" << endl;
      cout << "0";
   }
   if(a_small_side < hypotenuse){
      otherSide = otherSideLength(a_small_side, hypotenuse);
      cout << otherSide;
   }
   if(a_small_side > hypotenuse){
      swapStore = a_small_side;
      a_small_side = hypotenuse;
      hypotenuse = swapStore;
      otherSide = otherSideLength(a_small_side, hypotenuse);
      cout << otherSide;
   }
}

double otherSideLength(double a_small_side, double hypotenuse){
   //a^2+b^2=c^2,
   //b^2 = c^2 + a^2
   //b = sqrt(c^2 + a^2)
double b = sqrt(pow(hypotenuse, 2) + pow(a_small_side, 2));
return b;
}
```

If someone wants to take a quick peek at this that'd be awesome.

Comment: When you move a^2 to the right hand side of the equation it should be negative. In other words, you are adding a^2 when you should be subtracting a^2.

Comment: "but I keep getting weirdly large answers" - such as? Care to share? Examples should be *part of the question*.

Comment: Please don't add "SOLVED" into the title. Just accept the answer that helped you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like you have a sign error.

If you check your algebra you will find that

a^2 + b^2 = c^2

means

b^2 = c^2 - a^2.

Comment: Ah! thanks!

I'm a huge dope, I appreciate that you took the time out of your day to help with my silly mistake ^-^

Answer (score 2):

There are some problems in your code, besides the correct algebra formula already spotted in Drist's answer.

For example, in general it's wrong to compare floating-point numbers with a simple `x == y`; it's better to use a kind of "fuzzy" comparison with a tolerance.

Moreover, computing Pythagoras's theorem simply applying the classical math formula is error prone, as squaring e.g. `a*a` can overflow. A better approach is described [here](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/06/02/whats-so-hard-about-finding-a-hypotenuse/).

Assuming c is the hypotenuse (`c > a`), you may do:

```
// b = sqrt(c*c - a*a);
double r = a / c;
double b = c * sqrt(1.0 - r*r);
```